# Groovy Switch statement with list of values

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I want to use Switch statement in Jenkins pipeline job.

```
def version = "1.2"
switch(GIT_BRANCH) {
  case "develop":
    result = "dev"
    break
  case ["master", "support/${version}"]:
    result = "list"
    break
  case "support/${version}":
    result = "sup"
    break
  default:
    result = "def"
    break
}
echo "${result}"
```

When `GIT_BRANCH` is equal to:

- `develop` - returned value is `dev` - OK
- `master` - returned value is `list` - OK
- `support/1.2` - returned value is `sup` - why not `list`?

Comment: So your question is essentially "what is the behaviour of Groovy `switch` if multiple `case`s match?"?

Comment: I'd like to use that multiple case match with mix of string values and variables. In my code, variable works only in single case match, which isn't good sollution for me.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

My guess is that the type of `GIT_BRANCH` is a `String` whereas `"support/${version}"` is a `GString`. If you convert the latter to a `String` it should work:

```
def version = "1.2"
switch(GIT_BRANCH) {
  case "develop":
    result = "dev"
    break
  case ["master", "support/${version}".toString()]:
    result = "list"
    break
  case "support/${version}":
    result = "sup"
    break
  default:
    result = "def"
    break
}
echo "${result}"
```

The difference between the two string types doesn't matter when comparing them to each other, but it can matter for other types of comparison, e.g. in your code you're implicitly comparing a `GString` with the elements of a `List`.